# The argument type 'MaterialApp Function(BuildContext, AppProvider, Widget)' can't be assigned to the parameter type. I am facing this error

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:resturant/providers/app_provider.dart';
import 'package:resturant/screens/splash.dart';
import 'package:resturant/util/const.dart';

import 'util/const.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AppProvider()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppProvider>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, AppProvider appProvider, Widget child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          key: appProvider.key,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          navigatorKey: appProvider.navigatorKey,
          title: Constants.appName,
          theme: appProvider.theme,
          darkTheme: Constants.darkTheme,
          home: SplashScreen(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> I have checked all the code the only error i am facing is in the code up where Iam assingining builder. I have spend time to solve this but i can't.